# Xamarin | Delete parent stacklayout with onclick of button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am trying to create a screen where the user adds players to a game. The screen starts with just one entry and a "X" button next to it. Below that is an "Add new player" button which just adds a new `StackLayout` with the same entry and button as before.

Now I want the "X" button to remove its parent `StackLayout`, in turn removing itself and the entry. I'm sure its a simple thing to do, I just can't find anything that works.

The .xaml file:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Enter Players:"></Label>
        <StackLayout x:Name="Players">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Entry Placeholder="Player" WidthRequest="300"/>
                <Button Text="X" WidthRequest="45" Clicked="DeleteBtn_Clicked"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <Button VerticalOptions="End" Text="Add Player" Clicked="AddBtn_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The .xaml.cs file:

```
public void AddBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var newplayer = new StackLayout
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Children =
    {
        new Entry() { Placeholder = "Player", WidthRequest=300 },
        new Button() { Text = "X", WidthRequest = 45 },
    }
    };
    Players.Children.Add(newplayer);

}
public void DeleteBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   
}
```

I tried a few different things from the Xamarin documentation and some other related internet forms but couldn't seem to get anything to work, so I just left `DeleteBtn_Clicked` empty.

Comment: you need to maintain a reference to `newplayer` and then you can use that reference to remove it from the `StackLayout`

Comment: I'm new to xamarin and still trying to get my head around it, how would something like that look?

Comment: I don't recommend manipulating the UI directly. Instead, you may want to familiarize yourself with the [MVVM pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) and use an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1), which will automatically update the UI using [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/).

Comment: this is really basic C#.  `var newplayer =` creates a local variable that goes out of scope when the method exits.  You need to create a class variable (or some class level data structure to keep track of it so you can later delete it

Comment: Thank you @Jason but I think I'm gonna look into what Julian said with the MVVM pattern and an ObservableCollection. Sounds like its the "correct" way of doing things